# How to sum all the value in a specific date in mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to sum all the values in a specific date in mysql but idk what is the right syntax

```
CREATE TABLE `trans` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `date_sold` datetime NOT NULL,
  `total` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `trans`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `trans`
  MODIFY `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

| id | date_sold | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-23 | 12 |
| 2 | 2021-02-23 | 6 |
| 3 | 2021-02-24 | 32 |
| 4 | 2021-02-24 | 10 |

now i want to sum all the values in that specific date

ex:

| id | date | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-23 | 18 |
| 2 | 2021-02-24 | 42 |

is that possible?

Comment: Common GROUP BY + SUM().

Comment: `select min(id), date, sum(total) from trans group by date`

Comment: @juergend `min(id)` - hardly... it looks like trivial row_number.

Comment: It is better not to use 'id' field in the result until you know why you need it (or until you explain us why...). Because there can be multiple ids in the original table assosiated with the same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative Use of ROW_NUMBER() function. Because ROW_NUMBER() isn't supported in below v5.8. First calculate date wise total and then apply id incrementally.

```
-- MySQL(5.6)
SELECT (@row_number:=  @row_number + 1) id
     , t.date_sold, t.total
FROM (SELECT date_sold
           , SUM(total) total
      FROM trans
      GROUP BY date_sold ) t, (SELECT @row_number := 0) x 
ORDER BY t.date_sold
```

Please check from URL https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5cc2305b465ac2454be5bdb1a9e8af4a